# SQLite select, how does it work (underlyingly)?

Tags: android, sqlite, leveldb

I am working with SQLite on Android.

I want to return 10 records from a 1000 records DB, based on a where clause. e.g. `select * from log where level > 5`. The column `level` is not indexed. How does SQLite retrieve the data? I assume it will go thru all the records one by one and filter out invalid record, correct?

In that case, would it be faster to just use a key-value store like LevelDb?

Comment: You ought not to worry about performance of such a simple query with 1000 elements. You mention the column is not indexed - why don't you just index it?As you describe it this sounds like a full table scan would be needed. With 1000 elements, again, this should not be an issue though. Also, you can just locally use some sqlite tool to try run queries on your computer and most tools can also show execution plans

Comment: "would it be faster to just use a key-value store like LevelDb?" -- that is impossible to answer in the abstract. Moreover, one hopes you are doing other things with your database, such as inserting data into it. You need to run your own tests with your own data and your own planned access patterns to see if your LevelDb approach will be generally better, worse, or the same as your SQLite approach.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume it will go thru all the records one by one and filter out invalid record, correct?

Pretty much, yeah.

This is called a full table scan, and will result in poor performance *if your table is big*.

If you're curious about how SQLite executes your queries, you can use the `EXPLAIN` keyword, either on-device or in the command-line sqlite3 executable (available in the `platform-tools` folder of your Android SDK).

If you run `EXPLAIN <your query>`, it will give you a string of the actual code that will run in sqlite's virtual machine when executing that query. This is rarely useful unless you're developing/debugging sqlite itself.

If you run `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN <your query>`, it will give you a high-level view of what'll happen, including which index (if any) is used.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not indexed it will perform a sequential (linear) search to find all records meeting that criterion.  This will require all 1000 records to be passed each time you do it.

If it is indexed then it will obviously use the index to find the records which will, in all cases, be much faster.

You should index it if you're going to do this with any frequency.  If it is a one-off, than indexing gets you nothing.  Even though the performance may not be noticeably faster, it is what indexes are for and it would be lousy design not to index it.